# How to unselect navigation child menu in oracle apex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, oracle-apex

When i Click navigation dropdown icon then sub menus display but first menu is selected by default. i just want to unselect by default.

[image]

Comment: Your code please ?

Comment: I am using oracle apex. and this is by default navigation menu.

Answer (score 0):

Change your menu static menu to dynamic query.
Or
use
Search Navigation Plugin
https://github.com/grlicaa/SearchNavigationMenu
or
Change Menu navigation template
[In apex 20.2 no menu selected by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN2CZ.png)